# git submodule update and authentication

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I've just started using git (like right this second). I've been invited to use a project that contains some submodules and I've been given permission through my Github account. When I cloned the repo, I got some errors:

```bash
$ git submodule init
Submodule 'js/Common/enginelite' (git@github.com:clientName/EngineLite.git) registered for path 'js/Common/enginelite'

$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'js/Common/enginelite'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is there a way to pass credentials during this? Is there something I have to do locally or on Github? Thanks!

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey helped me. a keychain just wouldn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in `js/Common/enginelite` if there's a directory named .git edit the text file `.git/config`. If there's a file named .git, it will have a line that reads 'gitdir: ...' look in that directory and edit the `config` file there. Hopefully the contents of the file will show you where you can add your username@ in.

Comment: Also found this on configuring ssh with explicit Identity files on SuperUser StackExchange: http://superuser.com/questions/272465/using-multiple-ssh-public-keys

Answer (score 0):

As a submodule is a separate git repository my best guess would be that you need to get permissions through your github account to access the main git repository EngineLit.git

I guess permissions are not inherited by submodules.

Comment: I can see the entire repo on github with my permissions. is there a way to add my key to my request?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your git submodule to use the same authentication method as the parent repo and hosted in the same org, you can use a relative path in the git submodule. Provide the relative path in the `.gitmodules` file like below:

```
[submodule "test-git-sync"]
path = test-git-sync
url = ../test-git-sync.git # use relative path to the git repo
```